# How to get or generate deploy URL for Google Cloud Run services

Tags: google-cloud-run

How to get the URL of deployed service programmatically in CI environments? The URL does get's logged after successful deploy but what if I want to extract and use the URL programmatically, as part of post deploy needs, e.g. posting the URL for acceptance test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to get the desired information:

1. You can use the [namespaces.services.get](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/get) method from Cloud Run's API and a curl command. Notice that it will require an Authentication Header and an OAuth scope.

```
curl -i https://[REGION]-run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/[PROJECT_NAME]/services/[CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME] -H "Authorization: Bearer [YOUR-BEARER-TOKEN]" | tail -n +13 | jq -r ".status.url"
```

2. You can use the [gcloud run services list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/services/list) command in one of your build steps to get the desired value. For example if your service is fully managed you can use the following command to get the Cloud Run service that was last updated.:

```
gcloud run services list --platform managed | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}'
```

3. Build a script using the Goolge API Client libraries (e.g. the [Cloud Run Google API Client for Python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/dyn/index.md#run)).

Answer (score 24):

Simply use the flag: `--format='value(status.url)'` with `gcloud run services describe`

Here is the entire command:

```
$ gcloud run services describe SERVICE --platform managed --region REGION --format 'value(status.url)'
```

Answer (score 7):

Extending [Steren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59439508/8896457):

With these Bash commands you can get url and save it in Secrets Manager:

First create empty Secret:

```sh
gcloud secrets create "CLOUDRUN_URL" --project $PROJECT_ID --replication-policy=automatic
```

Then:

```sh
gcloud run services describe $APP_NAME --platform managed --region $CLOUD_REGION --format 'value(status.url)' --project $PROJECT_ID | gcloud secrets versions add "CLOUDRUN_URL" --data-file=- --project $PROJECT_ID
```

or version with added "/some/address"

```sh
CLOUDRUN_URL=$(gcloud run services describe $APP_NAME --platform managed --region $CLOUD_REGION --format 'value(status.url)' --project $PROJECT_ID)   # capture first string.
echo "$CLOUDRUN_URL/some/address/" | gcloud secrets versions add "CLOUDRUN_URL" --data-file=- --project $PROJECT_ID
```

And then you can load it as needed from Secrets Manager:

```sh
export CLOUDRUN_URL=$(gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="CLOUDRUN_URL" --project $PROJECT_ID )
```