# Is it possible to run 2 containers on a CloudRun service?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a deep learning-based app for image processing that uses user validation and Postgres database for storing the results. The following is the desired architecture for my app.

[image]

In order to keep it free for the long run time, I decided to deploy it using CloudRun serverless service within GCP. The following shell script is used to deploy it, which basically builds the docker image on the Docker registry and then deploys it as a service.

```sh
# Build container image 
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/$(gcloud config get-value project)/$APP_NAME

# Deploying to Cloud Run
gcloud run deploy ${SERVICE_NAME} --image gcr.io/$(gcloud config get-value project)/$APP_NAME --platform=managed --region=${REGION} --allow-unauthenticated 

#Update for CloudSQL connection
gcloud run services update ${SERVICE_NAME} \
    --platform=managed \
    --region=${REGION}\
    --add-cloudsql-instances $INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME \
    --set-env-vars CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME=$INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME,DB_USER=$DB_USER,DB_PASS=$DB_PASS,DB_NAME=$DB_NAME
```

Once the service has been built the next step could be setting up the keycloak container for users validation as shown below.

```yaml
- image: >-
    quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
  ports:
  - name: tcp
    containerPort: 8443
  env:
  - name: DB_VENDOR
    value: postgres
  - name: DB_ADDR
    value: <IP_ADDRESS>
  - name: DB_DATABASE
    value: <DB_NAME>
  - name: DB_SCHEMA
    value: public
  - name: DB_USER
    value: postgres
  - name: DB_PASSWORD
    value: postgres
  - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
    value: admin
  - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
    value: admin
```

However, this doesn't seem to work for Cloud Run configuration. Did anyone tried to achive something similar?

Comment: You have clearly 2 services: one for the API, one for the authN/authZ (keycloack). Why don't you create 2 Cloud Run services? Did I miss something?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere you got it right and seems reasonable to create 2 separate services, however, I've got no clue how to link one service to another.

Comment: It's HTTP communication. When you deploy the first service, you will get a URL. Put this url in the parameter of the second one, in the env var for example, and it should work easily.  Have a try, and come back here if you are stuck!

Comment: I'm kinda stuck at building keycloak's service by itself. I'm trying without success to deploy it using a docker file.
```ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.update) Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

Comment: Have a look to Cloud Logging to have more detail on the startup issue details.

Comment: Instead of putting a URL of the other CloudRun services into the parameters (environment) of a given service, you can use the GCP API and lookup services dynamically - see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59426990/854737

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Run supports one container per service. You can run almost anything you want inside one container. To run two containers requires two services.

Comment: Fair enough, however, doesn't seem feasible to build a container registry out for a keycloak instance. This post even shows some trade-offs of implementing a keycloak service using Cloud Run.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130538/run-keycloak-with-googlecloud-run

Comment: @MiguelRueda - However, your question is not about how to deploy keycloak. That is a different question/problem.

Comment: I've just opened a new question with this issue, since I'm having problems with keycloak's deployment as well.